# Closed curve in PSTricks

Tags: pstricks

Consider the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pstricks-add}

\def\side{%
  \psline(-2,2)(-1,2)
  \psarc(0,2){1}{180}{0}
  \psline(1,2)(2,2)
  \psline(-1,1)(0,2)(1,1)
}

\begin{document}

\def\length{60}
\psset{unit=79pt}
\begin{pspicture}(-2,-2)(2.15,2.15)
  \multido{\iA=0+90,\iB=-2+1}{4}{%
   \psset{offset=12pt,nrot=:U}
    \rput{\iA}(0,0){\side}
    \pcline[linestyle=dotted]{|<*->|*}(\iB,2)(!\iB\space 1 add 2)
    \ncput*{\length\,cm}
    \pcline[linestyle=dotted]{|<*->|*}(!2 \iB\space 1 add)(2,\iB)
    \ncput*{\length\,cm}
  }
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

As can be seen, the curve in not closed. How do I do this (or at least make it look closed; I don't need to fill the inner, so making it look closed is actually enough)?

Note: If someone has a 'simpler' solution than the ones already provided, I would be glad to see it.

Comment: You can work with `\pscustom`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you don't want to fill the region bounded by segments, then `linecap=1` will help here! Note that `linecap` affects the ends of each line rather than the corner (don't confused it with `linejoin`). For `linejoin` see my bonus answer.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pstricks-add}

\def\side{%
  \psline(-2,2)(-1,2)
  \psarc(0,2){1}{180}{0}
  \psline(1,2)(2,2)
  \psline(-1,1)(0,2)(1,1)
}

\begin{document}

\def\length{60}
\psset{unit=79pt,linecap=1}
\begin{pspicture}(-2,-2)(2.15,2.15)
  \multido{\iA=0+90,\iB=-2+1}{4}{%
   \psset{offset=12pt,nrot=:U}
    \rput{\iA}(0,0){\side}
    \pcline[linestyle=dotted]{|<*->|*}(\iB,2)(!\iB\space 1 add 2)
    \ncput*{\length\,cm}
    \pcline[linestyle=dotted]{|<*->|*}(!2 \iB\space 1 add)(2,\iB)
    \ncput*{\length\,cm}
  }
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

### Bonus answer

But if you want to change the corner of concatenated lines, then use `linejoin`.

[image]

Comment: Both nice code and explanation!

Comment: I guess `inecap=2` is what I want in this case; do you agree?

Comment: @SvendTveskæg: Yes. You can also use `linecap=2` in your case because it looks good.

Comment: @Herbert Maybe you should change http://tug.org/PSTricks/Examples/Gallery/exa069.tex to include this refinment.

Answer (score 7):

You must draw a closed curve. A line is an opened curve, you can close it e.g. with `\pscustom` and `\closepath`. `\pscustom` can include also `\multido` constructs. See the following example for different ways:

```
\documentclass[pstricks, border=3pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{multido}

\begin{document}
\SpecialCoor
\begin{pspicture}(10,2)
\psset{linewidth=10\pslinewidth}

\psline(0,0)(2,0)(2,1)(0,1)(0,0)

\rput(3,0){%
  \pscustom{%
    \psline(0,0)(2,0)(2,1)(0,1)(0,0)
    \closepath
  }%
}%

\rput(6.5,0.8){%
  \psline(1;-45)(1;45)
  \psline(1;45)(1;135)
  \psline(1;135)(1;225)
  \psline(1;225)(1;315)
}

\rput(9,0.8){%
  \pscustom{%
    \moveto(1;-45)
    \multido{\i=45+90}{4}{%
      \psline(1;\i)
    }%
    \closepath
  }%
}%
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

This gives:

[image]

You cannot use `\rput` inside of `\pscustom` to position the lines (at the moment don't know the reason for this). So you need to change the `\multido` part. Here is a part of your document changed to have close curves (maybe there is a more elegant way):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pstricks-add}

\begin{document}

\def\length{60}
\psset{unit=79pt}
\begin{pspicture}(-2,-2)(2.15,2.15)
  \psset{offset=12pt,nrot=:U}
  \pscustom{%
    \moveto(2,2)
    \multido{\iA=-90+-90,\iB=0+-90}{4}{%
      \psarc(2;\iB){1}{!\iB\space 90 add}{!\iB\space 90 sub}
      \rlineto(1;\iA)}
    \closepath
  }
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for the illustrative answer! For some reason I cannot get it to work with my example. Can I make you edit your post to include a closed curve for my code?

Comment: @SvendTveskæg I edited my post and added a part of your document to show how it might work. `\rput` doesn't work properly inside `\pscustom`.

Comment: Can we have 4 line segments in `\pscustom` to create a closed curve but each segment has different color?

Comment: @DonutE.Knot No, because `\pscustom` uses a single path and a single `stroke` command.

Comment: What is wrong with the next?


\pscustom{
\psline(1,0)(0,4)(-1,0)
\psellipticarc(0,0)(1,.5){180}{360}
\closepath}

I tried to use linejoin, linecap, nothing works.